# Black screen when installing Nvidia Drivers

Tags: nvidia

I have just recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 and decided to install the necessary Nvidia driver:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Then I reboot and find to have the black screen. I went into the terminal with Control-Alt-F1 and executed the following and rebooted:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
```

But I still get the black screen. How can i fix this?

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current`

Comment: Ok, I tried doing that and I still get the black screen. When I went and logged into the terminal, I also tried startx but that didn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these commands on virtual console(ctrl+alt+F1),

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: Apparently there is no such file or directory as /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Comment: But I tried the second command but it is still a black screen and startx doesn't work either

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` in virtual console.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the Nvidia Proprietary drivers and you get a black screen, you probably need to set `nomodeset`. So try to install the driver again and then do the following to get around the black screen.

To do this you need to:

1. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting, until you get to the Grub boot menu.
2. Select your boot option and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit it.
3. Edit the line that has `"quiet splash"` in it to `"quiet splash nomodeset"`
4. Try booting that by pressing <kbd>F10</kbd>.
5. If it works, make it permenant by editing /etc/default/grub to display the same in that particular line. Remember to do a `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Comment: I tried the method that you have stated and only to find out that it doesn't work for me. I am going to have to find another way to install the Nvidia Drivers

Answer (score 0):

This site always works for me:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-the-Latest-NVIDIA-331-20-Drivers-in-Ubuntu-13-10-399182.shtml